# ArduinoJson- unexplained '.size()' behaviour

Tags: json

I'm using an ESP8266, ArduinoJson v6.21.5. PlatformIO, and Vscode.

The config file is saved and read correctly to the ESP8266's flash:

```cpp
{
    "gen_pubTopic": [
        "DvirHome/Messages",
        "DvirHome/log",
        "DvirHome/debug"
    ],
    "subTopic": [
        "DvirHome/Light/int/KitchenLEDs",
        "DvirHome/All",
        "DvirHome/Light/int",
        "DvirHome/Light"
    ],
    "pubTopic": [
        "DvirHome/Light/int/KitchenLEDs/Avail",
        "DvirHome/Light/int/KitchenLEDs/State"
    ]
}
```

In case the config file is missing, `t[]`, `t2[]`, and `t3[]` are hard-coded to avoid boot failure.

There are 3 `for` loops to read topics (from the config file or from hard-coded).

The unexplained part is:

1. The config file is saved and read as expected, and the code runs without any failure.
2. when the `for` loop contains `DOC["gen_pubTopic"].size()` topics are read as expected, but when it is defined as `DOC["gen_pubTopic"].size() |3` it crashes.
3. `x`, `x2`, and `x3` are defined before each `for` loop. Again, once as defined in 2), still no change.
4. At some part it happened at the 3rd `for` loop, and sometimes at the 2nd `for` loop.
5. Printing `xi` values shows the expected values.
6. To make it clear - without using "fallback annotation" `|2` the code runs without crashing.
7. In all stages above - the fallback stage is not tested (meaning- config file is saved and read), and crashes happens when "fallback annotation" is added.

Appreciate any lead why.

```cpp
void start_iot2(JsonDocument &DOC)
{
       
  /* Default values */
  const char *t[] = {"DvirHome/Messages", "DvirHome/log", "DvirHome/debug"};
  const char *t2[] = {"DvirHome/Device", "DvirHome/All"};
  const char *t3[] = {"DvirHome/Device/Avail", "DvirHome/Device/State"};
    
  uint8_t x = DOC["gen_pubTopic"].size() | 3;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
    /* Some Code */
    /* debug code */
    Serial.print("Gen_");
    Serial.println(i);
  }

  uint8_t x2 = DOC["subTopic"].size() | 2;    
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < x2; i++)
  {
    /* Some Code */
    /* debug code */
    Serial.print("Sub_");
    Serial.println(i);
  }
    
  uint8_t x3 = DOC["pubTopic"].size() | 2;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < x3; i++)
  {
    /* Some Code */ 
    /* debug code */
    Serial.print("Pub_");
    Serial.println(i);
  }
  
  iot.start_services(extMQTT);
}
```

**Edit_1**
Added `/*debug Code */` to for loops.
At some point, the Serial Monitor showed:

```
Sub_0
Sub_1
Sub_2
Sub_3
Sub_4
Sub_5
```

while the size of the `SubTopic` array is **4** and `|2` as default.

Comment: I don't know what you expected `| 3` to do.

Comment: `|3` is set as a value in case config file does not exist

Comment: I'm afraid that you don't know what `| value` actually means. Please [edit] your question and describe what you think it does in detail.

Comment: *|3 is set as a value in case config file does not exist* - that isn't what it is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "fallback notation" you're referring to is [`JsonVariant::operator|`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonvariant/or/) and only works for [`JsonVariant`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonvariant/).

In your program, you apply `|` to an `unsigned long`, so the [built-in bitwise "or" operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) applies. It performs a bit-by-bit "or" operation (for example `2 | 4` is `6`).

In other words, `doc["key"] | 4` behaves as you describe, but not `doc.size() | 4`.

Unlike many other languages, you cannot use [logical "or"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) (`||`) either because it returns a boolean.
So, if you want to make minimal changes to your code, you'll have to do something like this:

```cpp
uint8_t x = DOC["gen_pubTopic"].size();
if (!x) x = 3;
```

Comment: I prefer explicit conditions instead of hidden C features: `if (x == 0) // ...` ;-) It does not irritate the casual reader of the source and shows the intention much better.

Comment: @Benoit - thank you for a concise answer

Comment: I wish to make sure that using `iot.add_pubTopic(DOC["pubTopic"][i] | t3[i]);` is correct (using `t3[i]` as "fallback")

Comment: Nope, I think not. It looks as if the argument to `add_pubTopic` is still a `unsigned long`, for which `|` means 'bitwise or'. This probably should not even compile, because `t3[i]` is a string.